# SQL Server is taking too long to execute for a small table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to remove non-alphanumeric from two columns and output it into a brand new table. I did this last time and it executed in about 30 minutes. The table only contains about 3000 rows and I'm connecting to a remote server, and I'm not sure what is the problem here. Please note that I have no permission to create function nor procedure.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT 
    [Customer ID], [Original Product Title], [Original Product Type], 
    [New_Product_Title], [New_Product_Type] 
INTO 
    Customer_Product_2
FROM 
    Customer_Product

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    UPDATE Customer_Product
    SET New_Product_Title = REPLACE(New_Product_Title, SUBSTRING(New_Product_Title, PATINDEX('%[^a-z0-9]%', New_Product_Title), 1), ''),
        New_Product_Type = REPLACE(New_Product_Type, SUBSTRING(New_Product_Type, PATINDEX('%[^a-z0-9]%', New_Product_Type), 1), '')
```

Comment: "I'm connected to a remove server".  That sounds like a performance killer.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question (and delete this one).  That question should include sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: It could be. It finished after about 30 minutes when I ran it initially, but I forgot to add something to the step before so I have to rerun this query. I left it running last night and when I looked at it this morning, it was still running after 17 hours. That's insane.

Comment: your loops could be infinite... not the best way to update

Comment: Is that all of your code? If you're updating without a `Where` clause, then just do the update without the `While` loop.

Comment: @WEI_DBA  WOW, awesome, it finished instantly. Is it because of the loop?

Comment: That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the loop since you don't need to check if `@@ROWCOUNT > 0` at all. An `UPDATE` statement will run on the set you give it, if no rows are in the set then no data will be updated.